# Relationship between Professor table and Course table

Tags: database, database-design

I'm designing a database where I have a **Course** table and and **Professor** table. The business rules are :

1) A professor can teach many courses. (This is obvious).

However, I get stuck in the second rule.

2) On a given semester, a course can be offered on different schedules, each of those offerings can be taught by a different professor. For example a typical freshman course on calculus has about 100 students every semester. The course is divided into 4 sections, each has 25 students and a different professor.

I have decided to model it as follow:

```
Course
{
   course_code
   prof_id
   course_name
   Primary key(course_code, prof_id)
}

Professor 
{
   prof_id
   prof_name

}
```

do you think this design is good? If not please provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Typically many-to-many connection where you instead of joining Course directly to Professor you would have a table maybe called schedule:

This table should have the following info:

```
Course
{
   course_code
   course_name
   Primary key(course_code)
}

Professor 
{
   prof_id
   prof_name
   Primary key(prof_id)    
}

Schedule
{
 course_code
 prof_id
 Primary key(course_code, prof_id)
}
```

You can also add some timeslots to the scehdule table so you can see which time of the week the course are held

Comment: +1. The word I have heard used for this entity is "Offering".

Comment: @joshido, thanks a lot. Can you also please help me identify the relationships between the three tables. I can see that there is a one to many between Course and Schedule, but the rest is unclear to me. Thanks

Comment: @NathanHughes thanks a lot. Can you also please help me identify the relationships between the three tables. I can see that there is a one to many between Course and Schedule, but the rest is unclear to me. Thanks

Comment: The relationship is 1-to-many between course and schedule, and there is also 1-to-many between professor and schedule